# Generating unique uibutton tags

Tags: ios, swift

I think this is impossible but I'm hoping someone knows a work around to use a unique int or string as a uibutton tag

Ideally I want something like this:

```
let uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString
myBTN.tag = uuid.toInt()!
```

It's frustrating swift only allows int as tags

Comment: Just how unique does the tag have to be? Unique to the view, unique to the app, or unique to the user? Are you programmatically creating multiple uibuttons that need to have unique tags?

Comment: Unique to the view and also unique to all the row ids coming from my db table.  These buttons are created on the fly programmatically

Comment: don't use tag in identifier for manipulation. Better put your needed buttons in array.

Comment: do you create one button for each row?
you can use a dictionary with the uuid as the key and the button as the value.

Comment: @dimipiax using an array of buttons worked perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to assign a unique integer to the tag of the view as you've described you can do something like this:

```
myButton.tag = Int(arc4random())
```

That will give you a very random tag which is unlikely to collide.

This is almost certainly a poor solution to the broader context though. If adding a UUID is actually correct, consider subclassing `UIButton` and adding a unique identifier property instead of using the tag.

Consider, as @dimpiax suggests, storing references to your buttons as properties, most likely an array of buttons, rather than using identifiers and going back to find the related button later.

Comment: I ended up creating an array of buttons instead of using tags.  thanks for the alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do a trick with a helper class and then, do it like this;

```
let uuid:Int = NSUUIDI.UUIDInt; // NSUUIDI() Not required here
myBTN.tag = uuid;

//Reverse (String value from tag)
println(NSUUIDI.UUIDStringFromInt(myBTN.tag));
```

Helper Class here;

```
//NSUUIDI.swift
class NSUUIDI:NSObject {

    private static var _uUIDs:[String] = [String]();

    class var UUIDInt:Int {
        get {
            let uUIDInt:Int = NSUUIDI._uUIDs.count;
            NSUUIDI._uUIDs.append(NSUUID().UUIDString);
            return uUIDInt;
        }
    }

    class func UUIDStringFromInt(uUID:Int) -> String {
        return (uUID < NSUUIDI._uUIDs.count) ? NSUUIDI._uUIDs[uUID]:"\(uUID)";
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up creating an array of buttons instead of using tags.  thanks for the alternative solution